# magento 1.6 captcha for register form

Tags: magento-1.6

While waiting for an update, I'm still using an old magento 1.6 version and we've seen spam on our register form. How can I add captcha to the form?

Comment: Extension can help https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 0):

An option is to implement a custom capcha module like here

https://www.gomage.com/blog/captcha-module-for-registration-in-magento/